# My mother’s monthly Norway pension stopped in 2020. We don’t know why

Tags: usa, pension, norway, retirement

My parents moved from Norway to the USA in 1958. They eventually started collecting a monthly pension from Norway.

My dad passed away in 2017, while my mom continued to receive the monthly pension. It stopped a couple of years ago.

How do we receive the funds that should have been remitted to her?

My sister represented my mother because my mother had dementia and was unable to communicate properly.

Comment: Don't you have any contact information? Surely you didn't just receive anonymous money in the mail? Call them and ask.

Comment: The reason is of course that pensioners living abroad often have incredibly long life expectancy.

Answer (score 3):

Some pension systems require proof that a receiver is still alive.

If such a letter was sent and no reply was returned, then the payments could very well be stopped.

So contacting them and informing them of the present situation would probably bring you your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

If you are living abroad and receive pension or disability benefit payments from Norway (NAV), an annual life certificate is most likely required.

NAV performs annual life certificate reviews to ensure that the payments are going to the right recipient.

Source:
[Life certificate for pension and disability benefit recipients abroad](https://www.nav.no/leveattest/en)

Comment: Canada also has such a system. A canadian friend (77) told me last June he had recieved a letter politely asking him if he was still alive which he replied to. 2 weeks later he had an unexpected operation which took 5 months to recover from. Had he not done so, dealing with his affairs would have been far more difficult. So these forms are important. We were also lucky with his expired passport, since after being informed, the Embassy sent someone to the hospital to deal with the renewal paperwork. The new passport arrived a few weeks later.

Comment: Similar in the [UK](https://www.gov.uk/state-pension-if-you-retire-abroad/report-a-change-in-your-circumstances) too

Comment: And the same in the [US](https://www.usa.gov/social-security-abroad) too.

Comment: In Germany, a **life certificate form**, if required, will be enclosed with the pension adjustment notification that comes around June/July of each year. Presently a *life certificate form* is **not** sent if you live in Australia, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Denmark, Finland, France, Hungary, Israel, Italy, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Poland, Sweden, Switzerland, Slovenia, Spain or the United Kingdom. [Renten Service – Life certificate | Deutsche Post](https://www.deutschepost.de/en/r/rentenservice/gesetzliche-rente/lb.html)